# How to make a route in Vuejs to not only go to a page but also to a specific element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Below is my navbar. Currently the app has two pages. The Home page has a header section, products section and contact section while the gallery page has has just images.

Currently when I load the page it takes me to home page and when I click gallery on the navbar it takes me to a different page of gallery. When I click Our Clients while I'm on the gallery page then it takes me to the home page. I'd like it to not only take me to the homepage but also to the element with the the id client. How can I achieve that?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link to="/" class="nav-link" id="products">Products & Services</router-link>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link to="/"  class="nav-link" id="clients">Our Clients</router-link>
     </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <router-link to="/gallery"  class="nav-link">Gallery</router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Routes definition.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path:'/', component: HomePageComponent},

        {path:'/gallery', component: GalleryComponent}
    ],
    mode: 'history'

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the hash to your link :

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <router-link to="/#clients"  class="nav-link" id="clientsLink">Our Clients</router-link>
</li>
```

then in routes definition define the `scrollBehavior` option :

```
new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {selector: to.hash}
        } else {
            return { x: 0, y: 0 }
        }
    },
    routes: [
          {path:'/', component: HomePageComponent},

        {path:'/gallery', component: GalleryComponent}
    ]
});
```